# passing image from one screen to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi all I have following scenario.

I have one 2 screens and one usable component. In my first main `GoalsDescoverScreen` screen I am showing all data, and in second `GoalsDetailScreen` screen I am showing individual data for each data.

In my usable component (`ItemView` ) I have Image and title. see code bellow.

```
    const ItemView = ({
     title,
     url,
     onPress,
    }) => {
    return (

       <View style={styles.container} onPress={onPress}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={url} />
            <View style={styles.textsWrapper}>
              <Text style={styles.companyName}>{title}</Text>
            <View>
                
       </View>
     );
   };
```

In first screen (`GoalsDescoverScreen` ) I am showing with `Flatlist` all goals which I am receiving from backend, and it was working successful. see code bellow

```
    const GoalsDescoverScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
   // fetching data from backend...
    return (
     <Screen style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={apiGoal}
          keyExtractor={(goal) => goal.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.paddingWrapper}>
              <ItemView
                title={item.title}
                url={{ uri: item.thumbnailImageData.url }}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("GoalsDetails", item)}
               />
             </View>
           )}
         />
       ) 
      </Screen>
     );
    };
```

Finally in my second screen (`GoalsDetailScreen`) I want to show each goal from (`GoalsDescoverScreen`) in new screen, and I am writing the following code for that

```
    const GoalsDetailScreen = ({ route }) => {

      const listing = route.params;

       return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <Screen>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={listing.url} />
          <Text>{listing.title}</Text>
        </Screen>
      </View>
     );
   };
```

In this way when I am writing for `GoalsDetailScreen`  title successfully appears in screen but not an image, please help me to resolve that problem

Here are data that I am receiving from backend:

```
    Array [
    Object {
    "amount": 1000000,
    "description": "Charity 1 description",
    "id": 1,
    "isActive": true,
    "organizationUserId": 14,
    "statistics": Object {
      "collected": 2629,
      "daysLeft": 2656,
      "supportersCount": 1,
    },
    "thumbnailImageData": Object {
      "publicId": "skcpez8lzezwgva2yeaj",
      "thumbnail": true,
      "url": 
 
 
 
 "https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdotwlx1/image/upload/v1616712587/skcpez8lzezwgva2ye 
    aj.jpg",
     },
     "title": "Charity 1",
    },
     Object {
    "amount": 1000000,
    "description": "Charity 4 description",
    "id": 4,
    "isActive": true,
    "organizationUserId": 14,
    "statistics": Object {
      "collected": 1031,
      "daysLeft": 6783,
      "supportersCount": 1,
    },
    "thumbnailImageData": Object {
      "publicId": "me4fbozwvq6sgffjfs4w",
      "thumbnail": true,
      "url": 
 
 
 
 
 "https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdotwlx1/image/upload/v1616712606/me4fbozwvq6sgffjfs4w.jpg",
    },
    "title": "Charity 4",
    },
    Object {
    "amount": 1000000,
    "description": "Charity 3 description",
    "id": 3,
    "isActive": true,
    "organizationUserId": 14,
    "statistics": Object {
      "collected": 632.15,
      "daysLeft": 11066,
      "supportersCount": 1,
    },
    "thumbnailImageData": Object {
      "publicId": "rzfstz2uqdswf0ha43bc",
      "thumbnail": true,
      "url": 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 "https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdotwlx1/image/upload/v1616712604/rzfstz2uqdswf0ha43 
    bc.jpg",
    },
    "title": "Charity 3",
    },
  
...
]
```

Comment: for Image element you have to give in style the width and height props and i think the right pattern: source={{uri: displayProject(project) }}

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I write `source={{ uri: listing.thumbnailImageData.url }}` and it starts to work

Comment: I wanted to write the same but bad copy - paste :D

Answer (score 0):

In `GoalsDetailScreen` screen should be written `source={{ uri: listing.thumbnailImageData.url }}`